# How to remove the "For Purchase" section from the Software Center?

Tags: software-center

The Software Center has a section of **For Purchase** programs —see screenshot below—,
which is annonying me every time I want to install something.

Is there any way to **remove** or **hide** these programs from the Software Center?

> #### Links to answers:
>
> [For **13.10 and higher** →](https://askubuntu.com/a/404153/4629)
>   [For **13.04** →](https://askubuntu.com/a/379155/4629)
>   [For **12.10** →](https://askubuntu.com/a/239606/4629)
>   [For **12.04** →](https://askubuntu.com/a/166332/4629)
>   [For **11.10 and lower** →](https://askubuntu.com/a/48004/4629)
>   Please leave a comment or send a mail to `jmendeth@gmail.com`
>   if it's not working for you or you're having trouble!

[image: The 'For purchase' section of the Ubuntu Software Center.]

Comment: what is 13.10 and higher means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's for the most recent version of Ubuntu like right now 13.10, and soon 14.04  believe the alpha/beta of 14.04 is soon out too.

Answer (score 17):

## For 12.04

<sup>Derived from  [Pavlos G. answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48004/4629) and inspiration from [Darmien answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/137253/4629).</sup>
**Different version? Go to [the list](https://askubuntu.com/q/47997/4629).

See the end of the post if you are in trouble and want to revert the changes.**

---

## 1. Ignore the purchasable apps

Open a **terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py
```

And press Enter. You'll be prompted for your password.
Then an editor will appear. Locate the following lines (hint: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> may help):

```
        doc = make_doc_from_parser(parser, cache)
        if not doc:
            LOG.debug("make_doc_from_parser() returned '%s', ignoring" % doc)
            return
        term_generator.set_document(doc)
        name = doc.get_data()
```

Immediately after those lines, paste the following (*including the spaces!*):

```
        if doc.get_value(XapianValues.PRICE) not in (""): return
```

**Note:** if you want to keep stuff that doesn't cost money, but has to be "purchased"
(like trials, magazines and other propietary stuff), replace `("")` with `("0.00", "")`.

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), open the Software Center and… voila!
There are no commercial programs!
You can close the editor and the terminal now.

### 2. Remove the "For purchase" channel (optional)

To also remove that "For purchase" item in the menu, open a terminal and type:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel_impl/aptchannels.py
```

Locate these lines:

```
        if get_distro().PURCHASE_APP_URL:
            channels.append(for_purchase_channel)
```

And disable them by putting a `#` in front of every line:

```
        #if get_distro().PURCHASE_APP_URL:
        #    channels.append(for_purchase_channel)
```

Save and enjoy a software center without ads!

---

### Side notes: The. files. are. packaged.

What does this mean, you ask? This means that,
whenever you upgrade your Software Center, the changes
will be reverted and you'll have to do this steps again.

#### Undo the modifications

If you want to restore the original state of the files,
open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center && exit
```

Again, you will be prompted for your password, this time on the terminal.
Type it and press ENTER. Don't worry if nothing appears when you type, it's to hide your password.
The terminal will automatically close when finished.

Comment: As I have said to others, it is best to make a backup before editing anything critical for a program.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS good point. But keep in mind that: **1)** The changes are trivial and easy to undo. It is unlikely that people will ever get lost. :D **2)** This files are packaged, so if you make a mistake you can just **reinstall** the package.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I've added instructions to revert, just in case ;)

Answer (score 12):

#### For 11.10 and earlier

You can edit:

`/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py`

and comment out (or delete) the following lines:

```
for_purchase_channel = None
```

---

```
#create a "magic" channel to display items available for purchase                                              `
        for_purchase_query = xapian.Query("AH" + AVAILABLE_FOR_PURCHASE_MAGIC_CHANNEL_NAME)
        for_purchase_channel = SoftwareChannel(self.icons, 
                                             "For Purchase", None, None, 
                                             channel_icon=None,   # FIXME:  need an icon
                                             channel_query=for_purchase_query,
                                             installed_only=installed_only)
```

---

```
if partner_channel is not None:
        #    channels.append(partner_channel)
        #channels.append(for_purchase_channel)
```

Of course, you should have in mind that consequent updates to `software-center` will probably overwrite the script...

Check out this [link](http://rbose.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software-Center) for more details ;-)

Note: for 12.04 the filename is `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel_impl/aptchannels.py`. The same steps apply.

Comment: Care to find a solution for 12.04? :)

Comment: If you replace software center with an old version http://askubuntu.com/questions/95497/is-it-possible-to-get-the-old-software-center-back then you can follow these steps.

Comment: On 12.04, these steps will hide the "For purchase" channel but not all the commercial entries. To hide them also, something like Darmien's solution would be needed. (But I want to find a way to alter the **logic** not the **GUI**).

Comment: I found it! Hide ALL commertial entries from EVERYWHERE!

Comment: @medigeek look at [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/166332/4629). If it doesn't work, tell me. I tested it in three different computers.

Comment: Making a backup of the file before editing is a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to hide commercial results for 12.04:

In /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/models/appstore2.py:

After the lines:

```
def set_from_matches(self, matches):
    """ set the content of the liststore based on a list of
        xapian.MSetItems
    """
    LOG.debug("set_from_matches len(matches)='%s'" % len(matches))
```

Add the following line:

```
    matches[:] = [m for m in matches if (m.document.get_value(XapianValues.PRICE) in _FREE_AS_IN_BEER)]
```

It should only change what is displayed, but I did not test it much yet, so use at your own risks. And enjoy an ad-free software center.

Comment: Great! Can't wait to test it. :)

Comment: Haven't tested it, but will do. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, here is the solution that worked for me in 13.10:

```
sudo aptitude install gksu
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py
```

Find this:

```
def make_doc(self, cache):
    """Build a Xapian document from the desktop info."""
    doc = xapian.Document()
```

And add this (make sure you have the right indentation of TABS (python requires this):

```
if self.has_option_desktop("X-AppInstall-Price"):
    if self.get_desktop("X-AppInstall-Price") > 0: return
```

BTW this was my first python evar :-)

Comment: +1 Can't verify right now, but added to the TOC as well. Thanks!

Comment: Works for 14.04, but it would be better if it could be turned on/off from UI. This solution is rather permanent. Never see apps for purchase again.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this it it worked for me: only FREE *(price not more than 0)* items are displayed.

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py
```

Find this:

```
def make_doc_from_parser(parser, cache):
    # XXX 2012-01-19 michaeln I'm just pulling this code out from
    # index_app_info_from_parser, but it'd be great to further
    # refactor it - it looks quite scary :-)
    doc = xapian.Document()
    # app name is the data
```

Then add the following code:

```
if parser.has_option_desktop("X-AppInstall-Price"):
    if parser.get_desktop("X-AppInstall-Price") > 0: return
```

Answer (score 2):

## For 12.10 and later

<sup>Derived from [jmendeth](https://askubuntu.com/users/4629/jmendeth) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166332/4629).</sup>
**Different version? Go to [the list](https://askubuntu.com/q/47997/4629).

See the end of the post if you are in trouble and want to revert the changes.**

Close the Software Center if it's open.
Now open a **terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py
```

And press Enter. You'll be prompted for your password.
Then an editor will appear. Locate the following lines (hint: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> may help):

```
        doc = self.make_doc(cache)
        if not doc:
            LOG.debug("%r.index_app_info: returned invalid doc %r, ignoring.",
                      self.__class__.__name__, doc)
            return
        name = doc.get_data()
```

Immediately after those lines, paste the following (*including the spaces!*):

```
        if doc.get_value(XapianValues.PRICE) not in (""): return
```

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and close the editor, but not the terminal.
Now type in the terminal:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel_impl/aptchannels.py
```

Press ENTER. An editor will appear again.
Locate these lines:

```
        if get_distro().PURCHASE_APP_URL:
            channels.append(for_purchase_channel)
```

And disable them by putting a `#` in front of every line:

```
        #if get_distro().PURCHASE_APP_URL:
        #    channels.append(for_purchase_channel)
```

Save the file, close the editor but not the terminal.
In the terminal, type:

```
gksu echo; sudo update-software-center && exit
```

Wait a bit, the terminal will automatically close when finished...
Then open the Software Center and… voila!
There are no commercial programs!

### Side notes: The. files. are. packaged.

What does this mean, you ask? This means that,
whenever you upgrade your Software Center, the changes
will be reverted and you'll have to do this steps again.

#### Undo the modifications

If you want to restore the original state of the files,
open a terminal and type:

```
gksu echo; sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center && exit
```

Again, you will be prompted for your password.
The terminal will automatically close when finished.

Comment: +1 **Thanks for contributing!** Well, this is getting pretty extense, so I think I'm gonna make a Python script that makes the appropiate fix depending on the version.

Comment: Gonna test on my 12.10, if everything's ready I'll link your answer at the top and make any other modification.

Comment: Just did it on my fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @jmendeth I will love to assist you write that script

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10. I'll see if I can make something...

Comment: However, also disabling the "For Purchase" channel seems to do the trick. Did you need to do that?

Comment: @jmendeth No, I didn't. BTW where is that "For Purchase" disable option?

Comment: Well, to disable "For Purchase" (see screenshot) you need to follow part two of my answer. I'm gonna suggest an edit to your answer.

Comment: Links at the top have been updated to point to your (now accepted) answer.

Comment: Confirmed working for Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score -2):

You can do this more simply by selecting View -> Canonical Maintained Software instead of All Software. This has the benefit of not being overwritten by software updates.

This may hide some additional items but at least it gets rid of the annoying magazines and for sale software in my experience.

Comment: Then you're hiding a 90% of all the software, showing only the software (commercial or not) that Canonical supports. What I want to do is remove the propietary software *only*.