# How to disable/hide paid apps from Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to remove the commercial programs section from the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47997/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-commercial-programs-section-from-the-software-cente)

Is there a way to disable or hide paid apps from Ubuntu Software Center (Ubuntu 11.10)? Or a way to permanently filter apps by licence: open source / closed but free / paid?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you click on the more info button on any application it tells you the price, the license and any other info you are likely to need.  I know it's not exactly filtering but it should help you make decisions on whether to install or not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. In the toolbar, where it says "All programs", you can click the arrow and select "From Ubuntu" instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that's only a partial solution. Doing as You suggest hides the category sidebar (i.e. cripples functionality) and works only for current session - it's not remembered when the Software Center is started next time.