# Is it possible to get the old Software Center back?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

Regarding the new Ubuntu Software Center that came with 11.10: I hate it. I think the old one is much more functional and is prettier than the new one. Is there any way to get the old Software Center back?

Comment: Dig through the Ubuntu package archives, or use the Lubuntu software center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is but it takes a bit of doing.

[old software center](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/software-center/download)

Download the previous version, Un-install the latest version using synaptic package manager it is called "software-center" It will want you to uninstall a ubuntu-desktop or xubuntu-desktop, let it uninstall this package then re-install it after it is done un-installing the software center.

next close synaptic package manager and open the download of the old software center with GDebi Package Installer, If you don't have it install it first. The old version will install only if the newer version is uninstalled first.

after installing the old version open synaptic package manager locate software-center, highlight it and on the file bar click -Package -Lock Version, this will prevent it from being updated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try Synaptic. It is also a package manager, but with a lot more functionalities.

Comment: I don't want to sound picky, but I don't like Synaptic. I'm just specifically looking for the Ubuntu software center that they had in Natty and older.