# How to hide one particular software from appearing in the Software Center & Dash

Tags: 12.04, software-center, unity-dash

You may think that dosn't matter, but I realy want to use Ubuntu 12.04 without this program, Pornview, in Software center for personal reasons.

Thus my question is, how do I hide a particular piece of software from appearing in Software Center and the Dash?

Comment: fyi this might be a start: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47997/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-commercial-programs-section-from-the-software-cente It is about removing apps from view in USC you need to pay for. Maybe someone with more coding skills can add in a line or 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and run the following command.

`sudo apt-get remove Pornview`

Comment: I am not sure, but probably the OP wants the application not to show up in Ubuntu Software Center...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't install this. But seems it all ways appear in Recommended programs. Thank.

Comment: rafalcieslak! You right!

Answer (score 0):

There is no graphical means to achieve this. Given an application with the package name `foobar`, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/desktop/foobar*.desktop
sudo update-apt-xapian-index
```

Then log out, and log in again.